# Get the first day of the week from a previously selected week

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a `datepicker` plugin where I get the day of the week (so far everything is fine and working). If I click again in the week field, the `datepicker` opens, but the selected day is today's (the current day). What I want is when I click in `datepicker`, its select the first day of the week select (Monday).

For example, if I have chosen the week `28 of 2017`, I want the day `July 10, 2017` to appear selected when I click the `datepicker`

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: What datepicker you're using? A jQuery plugin? A stand-alone thing? Native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a simple logic.

- Accept week number and multiply it by 7. You will have nth day.
- Create a variable (`baseDay`) that will hold the day to be selected.
- Create a date object for this day.
- Now fetch the day of this date and subtract `baseDay` from it. You will get number of days to subtract to get necessary date.
- Subtract those days and you have your date.

```js
function getStartOfWeek(weekNo) {
  var baseDay = 1; // For Monday
  var today = new Date();
  var date = new Date(today.getFullYear(), 0, weekNo * 7);
  var day = date.getDay();

  console.log(date, date.getDay())
  if (day > baseDay)
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - (day - baseDay))
  console.log(date, date.getDay())
}

getStartOfWeek(28)
```

**Note:** this is not the complete solution. Above logic is to get the necessary date. Once you have a date, you will have to set it to the datepicker. This part will be specific to plugin used and can be incorporated easily.